Is the set of $L^2([0,1])$ functions $g$ s.t. $g\circ \psi = f\circ \phi$ for fixed $f\in L^2$ and some $\phi_*(dx)=dx, \psi_*(dx)=dx$ closed?
Consider the $L^2$ space for the Lebesgue measure $dx$, i.e., the set of functions $f:[0,1]\to \mathbb{R}$ such that $\int_{0}^{1}|f(x)|^2dx<\infty$. Fix one function $f\in L^2$ and the space of $dx$-invariant transforms $\textrm{Inv}(dx)$ i.e. the set of measurable functions $\phi:[0,1]\to [0,1]$ such that $\phi_* dx = dx$. Here, $\phi_* \mu$ where $\mu$ is a measure represents the pushforward of a measure defined by $\phi_* \mu(A)=\mu(\phi^{-1}(A))$.
We can define a subset of $L^2$ by $[f] = \{g\in L^2|\exists \phi, \psi \in \textrm{Inv}(dx) \textrm{ s.t. } g\circ \phi=f\circ \psi\}$. Now, the main question is as follows:
Question. Is $[f]$ closed in $L^2$?
Background. I am considering an action of a semigroup $\textrm{Inv}(dx)$ on $L^2$ by $g\circ \phi$ for $g\in L^2,\phi\in \textrm{Inv}(dx)$. The relation $f\sim g\Leftrightarrow f\circ \phi =g\circ \psi$ for some $\phi,\psi  \in \textrm{Inv}(dx)$ defines an equivalence relation, and to see topological properties of the quotient space $L^2/\textrm{Inv}(dx)$, I want to investigate the closedness of $[f]$. For example, the closed and another condition implies the quotient is complete; see here.
My attempt. To start, I considered a trivial case where $f(x)=0$. Then $[0]=\{g\in L^2|\exists \phi,\psi\in \textrm{Inv}(dx) \textrm{ s.t. }g\circ \phi = 0\}$. I think a function like $\phi(x)=x$ for $x\in (0,1]$ but $\phi(0)=1$ should preserve $dx$ since leaving out a few points should not affect the measure. So I am guessing that $[0]$ is the set of functions that are zero almost everywhere, but in $L^2$ space, such functions are identified as $f(x)=0$ anyway, so in that sense, we should have $[0]=\{0\}$, which is closed.
However, this is a very hand-wavy argument that I do not know how to make it rigorous. Moreover, this only covers the trivial situation and considering general functions seems hard.
